# Run files via cmd in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmd

In my c++ program I need to open a txt file using another application(imagine *EXCEL*). How should I do that in code correctly?
Maybe I should use something like `system("start file.txt EXCEL.exe");`

Comment: The file would probably go after the excel executable (not sure if that is valid), but that will only work if excel is on your path, if not you will need to fully specify the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would simply be:

```cpp
system("excel.exe file.txt");
```

See [Command Line Switches for Office Products](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#ID0EAABAAA=Excel) for more information.

How it works will depend on the application because applicatons decide how they handle their command line parameters. If you want a universal way, use:

```cpp
system("open file.txt"); // Windows
system("xdg-open file.txt"); // Linux
```

This will open a file with the default application for that file.

Answer (score 0):

```
system("app.exe file.txt");
```

will work.
no need to write start at the beginning.
if app.exe and file.txt not in the same place then before app.exe must be the path
 
of the file.